# How many processes does this program create?

Tags: c, fork

```
...
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++){
      switch(fork()){
        case 0:
          sleep(1);
          break;
        default:
          sleep(1);
       }
    }
    while(i--) wait(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Hi. I'm trying to understand processes and forks.

I'm not sure how many processes does this code snippet create.

1 for the main program, then the main program duplicates itself (a child process is created), and then the child duplicates itself (2 children and the main process).

So those are 3 processes.

Am I correct or am I missing something?

Comment: It was an exam question.

Comment: The `break` breaks out of the **switch**, not the loop. Is that what you're not understanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `for` loop in the main thread (t1) that will call `fork()` twice (-> t1.1, t1.2).  The first forked-thread (t1.1) has one more iteration, so it creates another (-> t1.1.1). Neither t1.2 nor t1.1.1 has any more iterations left, so no more threads forked.

This leaves us with 4 threads altoghether

Answer (score 1):

Note that the behavior of the two cases in the switch are identical: sleep(1) then continue w/ the loop.  Since your solution had the two behaving differently (one created a child, the other did not), I'd say you are missing something.